# Generate a key for kafka messages that haven't any, in two topics, in order to merge / join them

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

From some row data for input in a `poids_garmin_brut` topic:

```
Durée,Poids,Variation,IMC,Masse grasse,Masse musculaire squelettique,Masse osseuse,Masse hydrique,
" 14 Fév. 2022",
06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
" 13 Fév. 2022",
06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
" 12 Fév. 2022",
06:17,72.2 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.3 %,29.7 kg,3.6 kg,54.5 %,
```

I managed to create two topics `poids_garmin_split_date` and `poids_garmin_split_valeursPoids` with that small method:

```java
public StreamsBuilder extraire(StreamsBuilder builder) {
   KStream<Void,String> streamBrut = builder.stream("poids_garmin_brut");

   // Les lignes qui débutent par " " portent des dates
   streamBrut.filter((key, value) -> value.startsWith("\" ")).to("poids_garmin_split_date");

   // celles qui ne débutent pas par " " ni ne contiennent "Durée" (header du csv) sont des données de poids.
   streamBrut.filter((key, value) -> !value.startsWith("\" ") && !value.contains("Durée")).to("poids_garmin_split_valeursPoids");
   return builder;
}
```

The topic `poids_garmin_split_date` now contains:

```
" 14 Fév. 2022",
" 13 Fév. 2022",
" 12 Fév. 2022",
```

and `poids_garmin_split_valeursPoids`:

```
06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
06:17,72.2 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.3 %,29.7 kg,3.6 kg,54.5 %,
```

Both topics have *null* = no key, but I need to add one to both of them, to link their content two by two :

```
123541, " 14 Fév. 2022",
123542, " 13 Fév. 2022",
123543, " 12 Fév. 2022",
```

and

```
123541, 06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
123542, 06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
123543, 06:17,72.2 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.3 %,29.7 kg,3.6 kg,54.5 %,
```

for example, so that I can merge these topics into a single one that would be:

```
123541, " 14 Fév. 2022",06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
123542, " 13 Fév. 2022",06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
123543, " 12 Fév. 2022",06:17,72.2 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.3 %,29.7 kg,3.6 kg,54.5 %,
```

that I can exploit.

If it's the good way that I should do things (I'm a beginner with *Kafka*),
how can I do this?

`map` operation? `transform` one?

---

From your answer, @OneCricketeer, I've attempted this:

```java
KStream<Void,String> streamBrut = builder.stream("poids_garmin_brut");

// Les lignes qui débutent par " " portent des dates
final LongAccumulator compteurDate = new LongAccumulator(Long::sum, 0L);

streamBrut.filter((key, value) -> value.startsWith("\" "))
   .map((key, value) -> {
      compteurDate.accumulate(1L);
      return new KeyValue<>(compteurDate.toString(), value);
   })
   .to("poids_garmin_split_date");

KStream<String, String> streamSplitDate = builder.stream("poids_garmin_split_date");

// celles qui ne débutent pas par " " ni ne contiennent "Durée" (header du csv) sont des données de poids.
final LongAccumulator compteurValeursPoids = new LongAccumulator(Long::sum, 0L);

streamBrut.filter((key, value) -> !value.startsWith("\" ") && !value.contains("Durée"))
   .map((key, value) -> {
      compteurValeursPoids.accumulate(1L);
      return new KeyValue<>(compteurValeursPoids.toString(), value);
   })
   .to("poids_garmin_split_valeursPoids");

KStream<String, String> streamSplitValeursPoids = builder.stream("poids_garmin_split_valeursPoids");

streamSplitDate.join(streamSplitValeursPoids, 
   (String date, String valeursPoids) -> date + valeursPoids, 
   JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
   .to("poids_garmin_join_date_valeurs");
```

that is resulting to a topic `poids_garmin_join_date_valeurs` having this content:

```
" 14 Fév. 2022",06:37,72.1 kg,0.3 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
" 13 Fév. 2022",06:48,72.4 kg,0.2 kg,22.9,25.4 %,29.8 kg,3.6 kg,54.4 %,
" 12 Fév. 2022",06:17,72.2 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.3 %,29.7 kg,3.6 kg,54.5 %,
" 11 Fév. 2022",05:54,72.2 kg,0.1 kg,22.8,25.6 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,54.3 %,
" 10 Fév. 2022",06:14,72.3 kg,0.0 kg,22.8,25.9 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,54.1 %,
" 9 Fév. 2022",06:06,72.3 kg,0.5 kg,22.8,26.3 %,29.7 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
" 8 Fév. 2022",07:14,71.8 kg,0.7 kg,22.7,26.3 %,29.6 kg,3.5 kg,53.8 %,
```

But I don't know how much that manner of doing things is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no attributes across both of these topics for you to join on, but you could consume both in a simple loop and add a simple counter... Or do the same with `filter().map().to()`

The easier solution would be to modify your original producer to iterate over your file in pairs of lines, and produce single kg+date events, rather than send separate events for every line, or having two related events with no shared information between them in separate topics entirely.

You also don't need the file header line in your topic

Comment: The `poids_garmin_brut` is the input topic, but I can't change its content. It's on the _Garmin Connect_ website the exportation of your weight, if your personal scale recorded it for you. This data is downloadable through a `csv` file, with alas the measurement records on two lines, each... So comes the work to try to flatten them.

Comment: How can I iterate over a topic by pair of lines? It's interesting.